# Image file not being stored in laravel project

Tags: php, database, image, laravel

Hello guys I need some help from you guys. I am creating a **laravel** project where I have modified the default **users** table to store more informations of users like **name** and **user image file name**. So that I had to modify '**RegisterController**' class where '**create**' function has been modified and I have also added an '**update**' method to store the uploaded image file. Below is my code of '**RegisterController**' class:

```
    protected function update(array $data)
{
    $path = $data['img']->storeAs('/public','ohgod  ');
    return $path;
}


protected function create(array $data)
{

    $filename;


        $filename = $data['img']->getClientOriginalName();
        $filesize = $data['img']->getClientSize();
        $this->update($data);


    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'img_name' => $filename,
        'img_size' => $filesize,
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'dob' => $data['dob'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

With this I also had to modify the **form** to get add informations of the user. And now when I register as a new user.I get every thing right in **users** table but **image file is not stored in the server**.

I am new in laravel so I don't know whats wrong with my code. I also haven't got any error messages. So help me guys.

I got the file storing code from the official site of laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem

Answer (score 2):

You have move image to folder before inserting into db

```
 $destinationPath='images';
       $filename = $data['img']->getClientOriginalName();

        //move iamge to folder
        $fileName = str_random(30).'.'.$data['img']->clientExtension();
        $data['img']->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
```

moved file will be available in public/images folder

Comment: sorry it didnt work it says undefined varialble $file

Comment: just change to $fileName

Comment: it says Call to a member function move() on string

Comment: it works after changing $fileName->move($destinationPath, $fileName); to $data['img']->move($destinationPath, $fileName);

Answer (score 1):

you can go to Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers trait and put your image code into register method

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
    $fields = $request->all();
    if ($request->hasFile('avatar'))
        $fields['avatar'] = $request->avatar->store('users', ['disk' => 'public']);

    $user = $this->create($fields);

    event(new Registered($user));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
        ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

then go to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController and append image into data array in the create method

```
protected function create(array $data)
{

    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'avatar' => $data['avatar'],
        'headline' => $data['headline'],
        'summary' => $data['summary'],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Does this solution saves the image in both database and in server public folder. Cause I wanted to save the image, only in public folder giving the uploaded image a unique name. And In database I only wanted to save the image name and size not image itself.

Comment: this size saves the image path in the database you can detect image size in register method and save to fields array and access them from data array in  the create method

Comment: Thank You Sir. This is the best method I have got so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
$image = time().'.'.$data['img']->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

$data['img']->move(public_path('images'), $image );

best way to store image in public images folder before sending to db.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `laravel` form then use

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => url('background'), `'files'=>true,` 'method' => 'post', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) !!}
```

and if you are using simple html form then use below code

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data"><form>
```

i hope it works for you.